# Preferred approach to loading binary file-streams into a Go Buffer

Tags: go, buffer, channel

## Brief

What is the preferred way to read in an input file using go, which avoids the buffering issues?

I am using go to re-write an audio processing command line app. The application slots into an audio chain and so will mainly be reading from and writing to stdin and out, although I am testing it with local files as it should work this way too.

Internally the audio will be processed via a pipeline made of go channels.

I thought that I would build my decoder and encoder packages first and then install them into a test-harness so that I could check that the audio was processed in and out cleanly.

There was a ton of distortion when audio was processed through the pipeline and it is evident that this is related to the speed at which the reader is sending data down channels.

I have managed to get the code working, but it feels as though I am using a sticking-plaster solution, hence the question.

## Further details

I wrote a simple test harness, which enabled me to isolate and test all components of the code individually. This meant reading byte-stream data into a buffer in its entirety and processing it as a single block - which worked fine, and then splitting the buffer into chunks and sending these chunks to the same code using channels instead.

This approach took an age, but I was able to identify that the root cause of the issue was the reader process. It was noticeable that the level of the distortion changed depending upon the size of buffer I was using with smaller buffers being worse. I managed to eliminate the distortion by adding a delay between each read, but this does not seem to be a very elegant solution.

Excerpt from main()

```
var WG sync.WaitGroup

    filename = decoder.Filename
    byteOffset := int64(40) // Starting from the 40th binary data point
    readBufferSize := 64000 // Adjust the buffer size as needed

    byteStream := make(chan []byte, 20)
    decodedSamples := make(chan [][]float64, 5)
    WG.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer WG.Done()

        err := ReadBinaryFile(filename, byteOffset, readBufferSize, byteStream)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        }
    }()

    WG.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer WG.Done()
        //decoder.DecodeData() // replaced with this simple version
        DecodeData(&decoder, byteStream, decodedSamples)

    }()

    // Close the doneProcessing channel to signal that decoding is finished
    // Encode and write samples as they arrive
    for samples := range decodedSamples {
        // Add for each sample group encoding
        WG.Add(1)

        go func(samples [][]float64) {
            defer WG.Done() // Decrement after successful encoding
            //fmt.Println("Test: Encode and write sample...")
            err := my1Encoder.EncodeData(samples) // Write handled within EncodeData
            if err != nil {
                // Handle the error appropriately
                fmt.Println("Test: Error Encoding Data")
                panic(err) // Adjust error handling as needed
            }

        }(samples)

    }
    
    fmt.Println("Test: Are we still waiting")
    // Wait for the asynchronous decoding to complete
    WG.Wait()
```

Test functions used...

```
func ReadBinaryFile(filename string, offset int64, bufferSize int, byteStreamChan chan<- []byte) error {
    const functionName = "ReadBinaryFile2"
    chunkSize := bufferSize // Set your desired chunk size
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    bufReader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    for {
        chunk := make([]byte, chunkSize)
        numBytesRead, err := bufReader.Read(chunk)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(packageName+":"+functionName+": Error reading:", err)
            break
        }
        delay := 5 * time.Millisecond
        time.Sleep(delay)
        // Send the buffered chunk to the channel
        byteStreamChan <- chunk[:numBytesRead]

        // Signal completion for the current chunk

    }
    close(byteStreamChan)

    return nil
}

func DecodeData(myDecoder *foxAudioDecoder.AudioDecoder, InputChan chan []byte, OutputChan chan [][]float64) error {

    const functionName = "DecodeData"
    debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName + ":" + functionName + " starting\n"))
    //numFrames := myDecoder.DecoderFrameSize
    totalChunkSize := 0
    var leftoverData []byte

    totalSamples := 0
    // calculate size of frame Sample for use in the decoder
    //frameSampleSize := myDecoder.NumChannels * myDecoder.BitDepth / 8
    debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName+":"+functionName+" Starting Number Channels [%v] Bit Depth [%v] \n", myDecoder.NumChannels, myDecoder.BitDepth))

    for chunk := range InputChan {
        //for chunk := range InputChan {
        totalChunkSize += len(chunk)
        combinedData := append(leftoverData, chunk...)

        // Create a copy of the leftover data and append the new chunk

        //debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName+":"+functionName+" Decoding Combined [%v] Chunk [%v] totalchunks [%v] ", len(combinedData), len(chunk), totalChunkSize))

        mySamples, leftoverData, err := decode16bitFloat64e3(combinedData, myDecoder.NumChannels, binary.LittleEndian)

        if err != nil {
            debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName + ":" + functionName + " Decoding Error in decdoding"))
        }
        totalSamples += len(mySamples[0])

        OutputChan <- mySamples
        if len(leftoverData) > 0 {
            debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName+":"+functionName+" Leftover Data: [%v] ", len(leftoverData)))
        }

    }

    debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName+":"+functionName+" Finished Decoding Audio, Samples processed: [ %v] Chunks Received [ %v ] Leftover Data: [%v] ", totalSamples, totalChunkSize, len(leftoverData)))
    close(OutputChan)

    //myDecoder.debug(fmt.Sprintf(packageName + ":" + functionName + "  DECODE DATA sent Done"))
    return nil
}

func decode16bitFloat64e3(byteStream []byte, numChannels int, order binary.ByteOrder) ([][]float64, []byte, error) {
    const functionName = "decode16bitFloat64e"
    var word uint16
    const max16Bit = 32768.0

    wordLength := 2 // 16 bits
    expectedBytesPerSample := numChannels * wordLength
    byteStreamLen := len(byteStream)

    // Calculate excess bytes and numSamples based on byteStream length
    numSamples := byteStreamLen / expectedBytesPerSample
    expectedEnd := numSamples * expectedBytesPerSample
    excessBytes := byteStream[expectedEnd:]
    byteStream = byteStream[:expectedEnd]

    myReader := bytes.NewReader(byteStream)

    mySamples := make([][]float64, numChannels)
    // set numSamples for each channel
    for i := range mySamples {
        mySamples[i] = make([]float64, numSamples)
    }

    // assumes interleaved samples meaning data is held in frame samples
    // The first sample of each channel is consequtive
    for s := 0; s < numSamples; s++ {
        for c := 0; c < numChannels; c++ {
            // Read 16 bits in little-endian format
            err := binary.Read(myReader, order, &word)
            if err != nil {
                errorText := ("Error reading binary data: " + err.Error())
                return mySamples, excessBytes, errors.New(packageName + ":" + functionName + ":" + errorText)
            }
            // Normalize to the range [-1.0, 1.0]
            mySamples[c][s] = float64(int16(word)) / max16Bit
            if err != nil {
                errorText := ("Error normalizing binary data: " + err.Error())
                println(packageName + ":" + functionName + errorText)
                return mySamples, excessBytes, errors.New(packageName + ":" + functionName + ":" + errorText)
            }
        }
    }

    return mySamples, excessBytes, nil // Return any remaining excess bytes
}
```